# Make a query based on a state change

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am making a Pokemon team builder, and am trying to use react-query as I am trying to use the cache features to not make so many requests to the open and public PokeAPI.

I have a dropdown that allows a user to select the name of a Pokemon. When a Pokemon is selected, I want the 'Moves' dropdown to populate with a list of that Pokemons moves for selection.

My initial approach was to use a useEffect hook that depended on the Pokemon Dex Number.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (pokeDexNum) {
        // fetch `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeDexNum}`
    }
  }, [pokeDexNum])
```

I have no clue however how to use this with React-Query. What I want to do is when a user selects a Pokemon, a fetch is made to the PokeAPI to fetch that pokemons available moves, and puts them into the `options` of the 'Moves' dropdown so that they can select moves.

From the code below you can see that when a Pokemon from the 'Pokemon' dropdown is selected, it updates the `const [pokeDexNum, setPokeDexNum] = useState(null);` state

```
<Form>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Dropdown
          label="Pokemon"
          search
          selection
          clearable
          selectOnBlur={false}
          value={pokeDexNum}
          onChange={(e, data) => setPokeDexNum(data.value)}
          options={[
            { text: "Tepig", value: 498 },
            { text: "Oshawott", value: 501 },
            { text: "Snivy", value: 495 },
          ]}
        />
        <Form.Dropdown label="Moves" search selection options={[]} />
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
```

How would I be able to use react query to fetch depending on whether `pokeDexNum` is updated

Example of query

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('getPokeMoves', () =>
     fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeDexNum}`).then(res =>
       res.json()
     )
   )
```

The above query sometimes fetches even when `pokeDexNum` is `null`.

Comment: have you constructed the `query` ?

Comment: added it in my initial post

Answer (score 2):

As stated in @Arjun's answer, you need to add the `pokeDexNum` state to the `queryKey` array. Think of it as a `useEffect`'s dependency. Any time the `pokeDexNum` gets updated/changes, a refetch will be triggered for that query.

Since `pokeDexNum`'s initial value is `null`, you don't want the query to fire before the state is updated. To avoid this, you can use the `enabled` option in `useQuery`:

```
const fetchPokemon = (pokeDexNum) => {
  return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeDexNum}`).then((res) =>
    res.json()
  )
}

const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(
  ['getPokeMoves', pokeDexNum],
  () => fetchPokemon(pokeDexNum),
  {
    enabled: Boolean(pokeDexNum)
  }
)
```

Also, it would be a good idea to add some error handling, I imagine you omitted this for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: You need to add your `pokeDexNum` to the `queryKey` of useQuery.

Here is my suggestion,

define a function to call `useQuery`. adding your `pokeDexNum` to the `queryKey`.

```
const useGetPokeMoves = (pokeDexNum) => {
  return useQuery(
    ["getPokeMoves", pokeDexNum],
    () => {
      return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeDexNum}`).then(
        (res) => res.json()
      );
    },
    { keepPreviousData: true }
  );
};
```

Then use it in your component,

```
const { data } = useGetPokeMoves(pokeDexNum);
```

Whenever your state changes, the `queryKey` will also change and the query will be fetched.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to skip the query if pokeDexNum happens to be null

Comment: you can use `enabled` in the options param.